# Differential Calculus Problems by Joseph Edwards

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives

I am difficulties with these problems from the book of Joseph Edwards on Differential Calculus

**The main problem is, I can't figure out how to get started with these**
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post only one problem at a time. Shall we look at the first problem first? By the way: very odd and not-pretty font and language, the book uses ...

Comment: In the first problem (77), there's not even a mention of $Q$ on the right-hand side of the equation! Weird ...

Comment: @MattiP. It's weird for me too, as I posted the question as it was

Comment: @MattiP. $P$ and $Q$ would be polynomials of $x$, I think. Smells like induction to me.

Comment: @MattiP.You can ans anyone you like or i can post them one by one too

Comment: @YNK I made a seperate post for ques 81 , So you post your answer wherever you like, and plese do it asap

Answer (score 1):

This answer is just a guide/sketch for (77). I think the notation should be like this:

$$\Large\frac{P}{Q}= a_0 + \frac{1}{a_1+\frac{1}{\ddots \, + \frac{1}{x}}}$$

where $P$ are $Q$ are polynomials in terms of $x$.

We actually have a recurrence relation $\large(\frac{P_{n+1}}{Q_{n+1}}) = b_n + \frac{1}{(\frac{P_n}{Q_n})}$ with $\large(\frac{P_0}{Q_0}) = b_0 + \frac{1}{x}$, where $b_n = a_0$, $b_{n-1} = a_1$, $b_{n-2} = a_2$, and so on...

**The following proof for (77) is by induction on the subscript of $b$:

**Base case** $(n=0)$: $\large\frac{P_0}{Q_0} = b_0 + \frac{1}{x}$.

*Task:* Show that $Q_0 = x$. Then, differentiate $\frac{P_0}{Q_0}$ with respect to $x$ and express the derivative in terms of $Q_0$.

**Induction case**: We have $\large\frac{P_{n+1}}{Q_{n+1}} = b_n + \frac{1}{(\frac{P_n}{Q_n})}$. Assuming that $\large\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{P_n}{Q_n})=\pm \frac{1}{Q_n^2}$, we need to prove that $\large\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{P_{n+1}}{Q_{n+1}}) = \pm \frac{1}{Q_{n+1}^2}$.

*Task:* Show that $Q_{n+1}=P_n$ (again, both are polynomials). Then, differentiate $\frac{P_{n+1}}{Q_{n+1}}$ with respect to $x$ and express the derivative in terms of $Q_{n+1}$.

Comment: Can you pls attempt 81 too

Comment: As commented by @Matti P., please post the other problems in separate posts. By the way, please accept an answer IF you're most satisfied with it. Thanks! :)

Comment: Yeah I am satisfied, I gues I wasn't ready for induction being used in the problem.

Answer (score 0):

78. The given expressions can be rewritten as

$\mathtt{C=\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\dfrac{r^k\cdot\,cos(k\theta)}{k!}}\,\,$  and  $\,\,\mathtt{S=\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\dfrac{r^k\cdot\,sin(k\theta)}{k!}}$

Now,

$\mathtt{C^2+S^2=\left(C+i\,S\right)\left(C-i\,S\right)}$

$\mathtt{\implies\,C^2+S^2=\left(\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\dfrac{r^k\cdot\,cos(k\theta)}{k!}+i\,\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\dfrac{r^k\cdot\,sin(k\theta)}{k!}\right)\left(\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\dfrac{r^k\cdot\,cos(k\theta)}{k!}-i\,\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\dfrac{r^k\cdot\,sin(k\theta)}{k!}\right)}$

$\mathtt{\implies\,C^2+S^2=\left(\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\dfrac{r^k\cdot\,cos(k\theta)}{k!}+\dfrac{r^k\cdot\,i\,sin(k\theta)}{k!}\right)\left(\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\dfrac{r^k\cdot\,cos(k\theta)}{k!}-\dfrac{r^k\cdot\,i\,sin(k\theta)}{k!}\right)}$

$\mathtt{\implies\,C^2+S^2=\left(\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\dfrac{r^k}{k!}\big\{cos(k\theta)+i\,sin(k\theta)\big\}\right)\left(\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\dfrac{r^k}{k!}\big\{cos(k\theta)-i\,sin(k\theta)\big\}\right)}$

$\mathtt{\implies\,C^2+S^2=\left(\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\dfrac{r^k}{k!}\cdot\,e^{\displaystyle\,(i\,\theta)k}\right)\left(\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\dfrac{r^k}{k!}\cdot\,e^{\displaystyle\,-(i\,\theta)k}\right)}$

$\mathtt{\implies\,C^2+S^2=\left(1+r\,e^{\displaystyle\,i\,\theta}+\dfrac{\left(r\,e^{\displaystyle\,i\,\theta}\right)^2}{2!}+\dfrac{\left(r\,e^{\displaystyle\,i\,\theta}\right)^3}{3!}+\cdots\right)\left(1+r\,e^{\displaystyle\,-i\,\theta}+\dfrac{\left(r\,e^{\displaystyle\,-i\,\theta}\right)^2}{2!}+\dfrac{\left(r\,e^{\displaystyle\,-i\,\theta}\right)^3}{3!}+\cdots\right)}$

$\mathtt{\implies\,C^2+S^2=e^{\displaystyle\,r\,e^{\displaystyle\,i\,\theta}}\cdot\,e^{\displaystyle\,r\,e^{\displaystyle\,-i\,\theta}}}$

$\mathtt{\implies\,C^2+S^2=e^{\displaystyle\,\left(r\,e^{\displaystyle\,i\,\theta}+r\,e^{\displaystyle\,-i\,\theta}\right)}}$

$\mathtt{\implies\,C^2+S^2=e^{\displaystyle\,r\left(e^{\displaystyle\,i\,\theta}+e^{\displaystyle\,-i\,\theta}\right)}}$

$\mathtt{\implies\,C^2+S^2=e^{\displaystyle\,r\cdot\,2\,cos(\theta)}}$

$\mathtt{\implies\,C^2+S^2=e^{\displaystyle\,2\,r\,cos(\theta)}}$

Differentiating both sides w.r.t r

$\mathtt{\implies\,2\,C\,\dfrac{dC}{dr}+2\,S\,\dfrac{dS}{dr}=2\,cos(\theta)\cdot\,e^{\displaystyle\,2\,r\,cos(\theta)}}$

$\mathtt{\implies\,C\,\dfrac{dC}{dr}+S\,\dfrac{dS}{dr}=cos(\theta)\cdot\,\left(C^2+S^2\right)}$

Hence, proved

Answer (score 0):

78. ***2nd Part:***

From the previous answer,

$\displaystyle\mathtt{C+i\,S=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\,\dfrac{r^k}{k!}\big\{cos(k\theta)+i\,sin(k\theta)\big\}}$

$\displaystyle\mathtt{\implies\,C+i\,S=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\,\dfrac{r^k}{k!}\,e^{\displaystyle(i\theta)k}}$

$\displaystyle\mathtt{\implies\,C+i\,S=1+r\,e^{\displaystyle\,i\theta}+\dfrac{\left(r\,e^{\displaystyle\,i\theta}\right)^2}{2!}+\dfrac{\left(r\,e^{\displaystyle\,i\theta}\right)^3}{3!}+\cdots}$

$\displaystyle\mathtt{\implies\,C+i\,S=e^{\displaystyle\,r\,e^{\displaystyle\,i\theta}}}$

$\displaystyle\mathtt{\implies\,C+i\,S=e^{\displaystyle\,r\left(cos(\theta)+i\,sin(\theta)\right)}}$

$\displaystyle\mathtt{\implies\,C+i\,S=e^{\displaystyle\,r\,cos(\theta)+i\,r\,sin(\theta)}}$

$\displaystyle\mathtt{\implies\,C+i\,S=e^{\displaystyle\,r\,cos(\theta)}\cdot\,e^{\displaystyle\,i\,r\,sin(\theta)}}$

$\displaystyle\mathtt{\implies\,C+i\,S=e^{\displaystyle\,r\,cos(\theta)}\left(cos(r\,sin(\theta))+i\,sin(r\,sin(\theta))\right)}$

$\displaystyle\mathtt{\implies\,C+i\,S=e^{\displaystyle\,r\,cos(\theta)}cos(r\,sin(\theta))+i\,\cdot\,e^{\displaystyle\,r\,cos(\theta)}\,sin(r\,sin(\theta))}$

On comparing,

$\displaystyle\mathtt{\implies\,C=e^{\displaystyle\,r\,cos(\theta)}\cdot\,cos(r\,sin(\theta))\,\,\,\,\,and\,\,\,\,\,S=e^{\displaystyle\,r\,cos(\theta)}\cdot\,sin(r\,sin(\theta))}$

Now,

$\mathtt{\dfrac{S}{C}=\dfrac{e^{\displaystyle\,r\,cos(\theta)}\cdot\,sin(r\,sin(\theta))}{e^{\displaystyle\,r\,cos(\theta)}\cdot\,cos(r\,sin(\theta))}}$

$\mathtt{\implies\,\dfrac{S}{C}=\dfrac{sin(r\,sin(\theta))}{cos(r\,sin(\theta))}}$

$\mathtt{\implies\,\dfrac{S}{C}=tan(r\,sin(\theta))}$

Differentiating both sides w.r.t r,

$\mathtt{\implies\,\dfrac{C\cdot\dfrac{dS}{dr}-S\cdot\dfrac{dC}{dr}}{C^2}=sin(\theta)\cdot\,sec^2(r\,sin(\theta))}$

$\mathtt{\implies\,\dfrac{C\cdot\dfrac{dS}{dr}-S\cdot\dfrac{dC}{dr}}{C^2}=sin(\theta)\cdot\,\left(1+tan^2(r\,sin(\theta))\right)}$

$\mathtt{\implies\,\dfrac{C\cdot\dfrac{dS}{dr}-S\cdot\dfrac{dC}{dr}}{C^2}=sin(\theta)\cdot\,\left(1+\dfrac{S^2}{C^2}\right)}$

$\mathtt{\implies\,C\cdot\dfrac{dS}{dr}-S\cdot\dfrac{dC}{dr}=C^2\cdot\,sin(\theta)\cdot\,\left(1+\dfrac{S^2}{C^2}\right)}$

$\mathtt{\implies\,C\cdot\dfrac{dS}{dr}-S\cdot\dfrac{dC}{dr}=sin(\theta)\cdot\,C^2\cdot\left(1+\dfrac{S^2}{C^2}\right)}$

$\mathtt{\implies\,C\cdot\dfrac{dS}{dr}-S\cdot\dfrac{dC}{dr}=sin(\theta)\cdot\left(C^2+S^2\right)}$

Hence, proved